# Handle mouse and touch events only inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to follow the cube code from https://codepen.io/jordizle/pen/haIdo/

Eventually the cube works on a project that I am working on. But I have run into an issue. The cube responds to events outside the div container that it is in. For example, if I use the mouse to drag on a different div, the cube which is on a separate div responds to the event.

I am not sure as to how to fix this issue.

I have created a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/sourabhtewari/75c6qcm5/2/

I am not much of a JavaScript/jQuery expert but this is the initializing method

```
var cube = new Cube({
    viewport: viewport,
    element: document.getElementsByClassName('cube')[0]
});
```

with viewport being initialized in

```
var viewport = new Viewport({
    element: document.getElementsByClassName('cube')[0],
    fps: 20,
    sensivity: 0.1,
    sensivityFade: 0.93,
    speed: 2,
    touchSensivity: 1.5
});
```

I see that the element where the events are being binded looks OK to me. Hence, I am in a fix as to why the cube reacts to events which are outside its parent div.

The Binding events look like these

```
 bindEvent(document, 'mousedown', function () {
        self.down = true;
    });

    bindEvent(document, 'mouseup', function () {
        self.down = false;
    });

    bindEvent(document, 'keyup', function () {
        self.down = false;
    });

    bindEvent(document, 'mousemove', function (e) {
        self.mouseX = e.pageX;
        self.mouseY = e.pageY;
    });

    bindEvent(document, 'touchstart', function (e) {

        self.down = true;
        e.touches ? e = e.touches[0] : null;
        self.mouseX = e.pageX / self.touchSensivity;
        self.mouseY = e.pageY / self.touchSensivity;
        self.lastX = self.mouseX;
        self.lastY = self.mouseY;
    });

    bindEvent(document, 'touchmove', function (e) {
        if (e.preventDefault) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        if (e.touches.length === 1) {

            e.touches ? e = e.touches[0] : null;

            self.mouseX = e.pageX / self.touchSensivity;
            self.mouseY = e.pageY / self.touchSensivity;

        }
    });

    bindEvent(document, 'touchend', function (e) {
        self.down = false;
    });
```

If someone could help me out here, I would be thankful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because mouse event listeners are bound to the `document` (whole page).

This is the part where the mouse events are being captured. Note the `document` variable which essentially references the page's document.

```
bindEvent(document, 'mousedown', function() {
  self.down = true;
});
```

**You can use a div in front of the cube to capture events instead:**

- Add a `<div id="cube-overlay"></div>` *in front* of your cube. Make sure it covers the whole "area" of your cube in all orientations.
- Grab that overlay div and pass that in the `bindEvent` functions instead of the `document`.

**Example:**

```
var overlay = document.getElementById("cube-overlay");

bindEvent(overlay, 'mousedown', function() {
  self.down = true;
});

// Make sure you do this change on all the `bindEvent` functions that 
// deal with mouse/touch events
```

**Updated Fiddle:**

Here's an updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/75c6qcm5/5/). In this fiddle, I simply gave an `id="viewport"` on your already existing `<div class="viewport">` element and used that as the `bindEvent` argument.